# using curly braces to run multiple commands that have spaces

Tags: terminal

i have recently learned how can i use curly braces to run multiple commands using curly braces
for example, i can create `10` files like this,

```
touch {1..10}.txt
```

or file with odd names,

```
touch {1..10..2}
```

I can also restart multiple process like,

```
systemctl restart app9-{server,client,test}
```

above command will restart services called, `app9-server` , `app9-client` and `app9-test`

now i have a command with a space in it,

```
vagrant destroy app9
vagrant up app9
vagrant ssh app9
```

how can i run above 3 commands using braces?

I tried,

```
vagrant {destroy app9,up app9,ssh app9}
```

and

```
vagrant {destroy,up,ssh} app9
```

but none of them actually works.

Can someone please tell me how can i run these commands using braces?

Comment: Does `vagrant destroy app9 up app9 ssh app9` or `vagrant destroy up ssh app9` work?

Comment: no it doesn't but `vagrant destroy app9 && vagrant up app9 && vagrant ssh app9` does.

Comment: when i run `vagrant {destroy app9,up app9,ssh app9}` it outputs as if i ran `vagrant` command only without any parameters

Comment: So you need to run those as separate commands, and brace expansion won't help much with that. See dupe^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In none of the cases where you use curly braces in your question are you running multiple commands.

```
touch {1..10}.txt
```

runs one command on 10 files:

```
touch 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt 10.txt
```

The command

```
systemctl restart app9-{server,client,test}
```

is still just one command:

```
systemctl restart app9-server app9-client app9-test
```

Brace expansion is used to perform a simple text expansion of one or several strings in a single command.

The three tasks you want to perform must be three separate commands.  You may do this in a loop if you wish:

```
for cmd in destroy up ssh; do
    vagrant "$cmd" app9
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
eval 'vagrant '{destroy,up,ssh}' app9;'
```

Notice the quotes.